# Как сделать незакрываемое приложение андроид

Tags: java, android, процесс, уведомления

как сделать так, чтобы приложение не закрывалось, а продолжало работать в фоновом режиме? Даже после того как пользователь его закрыл из меню. Есть такие приложения, которые закрываешь, а уведомления и их работа в фоне остаётся.
Я сделал постоянное уведомление для этого, но всё равно приложение закрывается.

```
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 1;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID";


Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
                notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
                notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
                notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Заголовок");
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Какой-то текст");
                notificationBuilder.setPriority(PRIORITY_HIGH);
                createNotificationMangaer(notificationManager);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: используй firebase. хоть приложение и закрыто, уведомление всё равно придёт

Comment: Погуглите foreground service, думаю, это то, что Вы ищете

Comment: "незакрываемое приложение" - это путь к созданию вируса, такого никто не допустит